# Preventing blank input not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to prevent blank input on an editable list item, I'm using the same code I use somewhere else but for some reason it is not working.

I have:

```
if(folderName == "" || folderName == " " || folderName.charAt(0) == " "){
        $(this).remove();
    }
```

It is removing the item if I do not type anything, though if I enter a blank space it doesn't call the remove.

Strange thing is I am using this exact same code in a different area and it's working fine.

Here is the full function:

```
$(document).on('focusout', '#folders li', function(){ //add class when lose focus/shorten name if too long
    var folderName = $(this).text();
    $('#folders li').removeAttr('contenteditable');
    $('#folders li').removeClass('active-tab');
    $(this).addClass('active-tab');
    if(folderName.length > 15){
        $(this).attr('title', $(this).text());
        shortFolderName=folderName.substring(0,15) + '...';
        $(this).text(shortFolderName);
    }
    else if(folderName.length <= 15){
        $(this).text(folderName);
        $(this).attr('title', $(this).text());
    }
    if(folderName == "" || folderName == " " || folderName.charAt(0) == " "){
        $(this).remove();
    }
    console.log(folderName);
})
```

html:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul id="folders">
        <li class="active-tab" >All Notes</li>
        <li>Work</li>
        <li>Personal</li>
        <li id="add" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></li>
    <ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use the `.trim()` function and then check the string's length.

```
if(folderName == "" || folderName.trim().length === 0){
    $(this).remove();
}
```

Note: The `trim()` function removes whitespace from both ends of a string.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim)

Comment: Brilliant, got this to work thanks! Think you meant <= 0 though? It worked changing it to that, completely forgot to try trim() myself though so thanks for the help, working as I wanted it now :)

Comment: Yeah, I meant `=== 0`

Comment: This could be simplified to `if( !folderName.trim().length ){}` if you know the `folderName` is a string. As any non-zero length is equivilent to true, and the `!` inverts the true to a false.

Comment: Sure, but I think checking for `length === 0` adds clarity for people not comfortable with javascript

Comment: Of course, your answer is the correct way to teach the solution, I'm just providing some extra ideas for people if they want to see them :)

Answer (score 1):

Check the space like this:

```
folderName.indexOf(' ') >= 0
```

So your check should be like this:

```
if(folderName == "" || (folderName.indexOf(' ') >= 0)){
    $(this).remove();
}
```